# Getting the interval between 2 dates in Moment.js and formatting in either minutes or hours in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Is there any way to get the duration in hours or minutes between 2 dates in Moment.js ... I cant seem to get it going, no matter what I try i cant get it working .. minutes dont show or it seems to round it up. some examples of dates im returning to react is;

```
start_time: "2023-07-12T14:00:00.000000Z"
end_time: "2023-07-12T16:30:00.000000Z"
```

I would like this to format at `2.5hrs` or;

```
start_time: "2023-07-12T14:00:00.000000Z"
end_time: "2023-07-12T14:30:00.000000Z"
```

I would like this to format at `30mins`. what i have so far, which just doesnt work.

```
import Moment from 'moment'

const Shows = () => {
    return (
        {shows.map((show) => (
            <p>{Moment(show.end_time).diff(Moment(show.start_time), 'hours')}</p>
        ))}
    )
}
```

Comment: There is a third parameter after 'hours' for precision, you will want to set to true so it doesn't truncate the 0.5 hours down to zero

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a third argument as `true` to get a decimal value instead of an integer.

If you want to format the duration in hours or minutes as a string, you can use the `toFixed()` method to round the decimal value to one digit, and then concatenate the unit symbol.

For example:

```
{shows.map((show) => {
  const diff = moment(show.end_time).diff(
    moment(show.start_time),
    "minutes",
    true
  );
  return (
    <p>{diff >= 60 ? `${(diff / 60).toFixed(1)}hrs` : `${diff}mins`}</p>
  );
})}
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hugle-x8yclc?file=/src/App.js).